# Count the films per genre watched by a person

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using a graph db (neo4j) and Cypher. 
I have three nodes: `Person`, `Film`, `Genre`, and two relationships: `GUARDATO` and `GENRETOFILM`.

A person can watch multiple films. 
A genre is related to multiple films.

```
(p:Person)-[gu:GUARDATO]->(f:Film)
(g:Genre)-[ge:GENRETOFILM]->(f)
```

I want to get the genres watched by a person and the number of films s/he watched of each genre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to count number of relationships named GENRETOFILM of the films
>   watched by a certain Person

Try this:

```
MATCH(p:Person {name:'Jon Doe'})-[:GUARDATO]->(film:Film)<-[ge:GENRETOFILM]-(genre:Genre)
RETURN genre, count(film)
```

Comment: I feel I'm not explaining things right. In this way I have the number of films watched by a Person. I wanna a list that show me for each genre how many films are of that kind

Comment: This is it what I want. Thank you!

Comment: I corrected the question for clarity and to match what was actually being asked.